Can't Install JDK 22 after computer crashed because "Another installation is in progress."
I am inexperienced in the Java language, so I am unfamiliar with this stuff. I have tried installing jdk-22_windows-x64_bin.exe before my computer crashed unexpectedly. After reboot, the popup "Another installation in progress" appears.
I have tried using other guides such as this one but despite deleting JAVA_INSTALL_FLAG the error still appears.
Otherwise, should I use a registry editor?

Did you delete both JAVA_INSTALL_FLAG files?

Delete that file in all three directories, and also clean your %TEMP% folder.

This seems more like a Windows OS user question rather than a programming question. https://superuser.com/

To 1 - I deleted all flags I'm sure
